# Win 10 (SP4) Iris Pro Graphics 540 - manually set resolution?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, intel-graphics, microsoft-surface-pro

I can't get my monitor to run in 4096x2160.

The highest available resolution listed in control panel is 3840x2160:

[image: control panel]

Same when listing "all modes" from the graphics adapter properties in hardware manager:

[image: graphics properties]

Monitor is *LG 31MU97-B* - the resolution is supported and the OSD keeps reminding me the recommended resolution is, indeed, 4096x2160 :)

- updating [drivers](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-31MU97-B) didn't add the desired mode even though the inf file lists it
- tried w/ "generic PnP monitor" as well

Connected to *Surface 4 Pro i7*

- the resolution [is listed as supported](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-nz/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-to-a-tv-display-or-projector?os=windows-10)
- tried connecting w/ DP directly and through the dock
- tried w/ "extend" and "external only" modes

I've tried adding a custom resolution w/ CRU, but that doesn't seem to be available on 4096px width (note the disabled "OK" button below)

[image: cru]

NB: this monitor has been used at 4096x2160 resolution (same cable)

Comment: Check if you have enough memory allocated in the BIOS for the card to use that resolution. Just to verify, next boot, give it a chunk more.

Comment: The device manager indicates 8gb shared memory

Comment: Have you tried using the [Intel HD Graphics Control Panel to set a custom resolution](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503125726/http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-029478.htm)?

Comment: @Vinayak: the control panel is not available with the custom drivers for Surface. Installing intel drivers renders the tablet unusable (had to do a restore)

Comment: Maybe it's a cable issue? Someone had a [similar problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro3-surfdevice/cannot-get-4k-resolution-on-dell-p2715q/6f6fca9b-a752-4c5d-bbdd-cf561a7b8436) that they resolved by switching cables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the problem is with the Iris Graphics 540 card.

It seems that displays can only be connected to it using
DisplayPort 1.2 / eDP 1.3 which maxes out at 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz,
or using HDMI limited to the older version 1.4a which also maxes out
at 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz.

You might try to use the less-limited HDMI 2.0
by adding a DisplayPort converter that supports it.
Such converters may be bought in stores or on Internet shopping websites.

Or if possible for your computer, add/replace the video card.
<sub>(Edit: The last sentence was written before I knew the post was about the Surface Pro.)</sub>

Sources:

- [Notebook Check - Intel Iris Graphics 540](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Iris-Graphics-540.149939.0.html)
- [Game Debate - Iris Graphics 540 Mobile](http://www.game-debate.com/hardware/index.php?gid=3295&graphics=Iris%20Graphics%20540%20Mobile)

Comment: interesting; in the spec originally linked to it's indicated that [Iris supports the resolution](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-nz/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-to-a-tv-display-or-projector?os=windows-10). I'll investigate HDMI 2.0 option

Comment: Do you know what adapter you're currently using? A further source verifies a DP -> HDMI 2.0 adapter is required if you're not using DP directly:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/9483/intel-skylake-review-6700k-6600k-ddr4-ddr3-ipc-6th-generation/4

Edit: Just spotted you are using DP directly - that doesn't match what I expected from the source after all.

Comment: @Jonno: I'm using DP directly and have used it on another system to drive at the desired resolution. Updated the question to disambiguate.